# no local computer physical store, only registry and smartcard

Tags: windows, certificate-authority, certificate

I'm currently encountering an issue whereby i cannot see the "local computer" physical store, under trusted root CA, when attempting to install a cert. Instead the only stores i see are "Registry" and "SmartCard".

The machine that i am having the issue is on a newly created Win 7 64 bit Enterprise VM - with latest updates.
I have tried this on a similar win 7 64 bit VM and i can see the store on that machine!

Currently at my wits end on this and would appreciate any help to find this store.

Comment: Do you have admin permissions?

Comment: Yes, logged in both as local admin and a domain user in the local administrators group.